# When did Julie's parents die?

Tags: chronology, he-man, masters-of-the-universe

In the film version of ***Masters of the Universe***, Julie is a teenage orphan, but when did her parents die?

At the end of the film Julie and Kevin are sent back in time and prevent the accident, and it seems very recent, but is it made clear when the accident was?

Comment: Did they see the film and die of shame?

Comment: @Valorum don't diss he-man. It's got Tom Paris from Star Trek Voyager and the headmaster from back to the future in it. What more can you want?

Comment: Every time I see that film, I can't help but laugh at the cop with the shotgun. He cocks it about fifteen times (emptying the chamber) and never even fires the damn thing.

Comment: @Valorum I've just watched it. His shotgun in the end has about 20 shots without re loading. I'm not sure how realistic that is?

Comment: Wasn't there a plane crash with her parents involved? (long time since I saw that film)

Comment: @Thomas yes. Her parents are dead at the start, we find out it was in a plane crash. At the end she stops them flying, but it's not clear *when* this happened

Comment: ah misread your question there,  when not why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julie's parents died in 1986, as can be seen from their tombstones.

[image]

Since the film was slated for release in 1987 (and appears to be set in the present day), we can deduce that **her parents have been dead for approximately a year by the time the film takes place.**

Comment: Marvellous stuff. Must have looked away from the TV when I was watching it the other night !

Comment: @ATB - Glad to help. This also ties up nicely with the her emotional state at the start of the film (where she's coming to terms with the loss and is starting to move on) and the final scene in which she looks physically similar, but perhaps a bit younger.